# Problems importing data from CSV and from SQL

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

So I have a script that uses:

```
read.csv("data.csv") -> y
```

But I want to be able to assign "y" by using:

```
sqlQuery(ch, "select * from table") -> y
```

The sqlQuery returns/provides the same data/columns that is in the .csv file. The problem that I'm having is the rest of my script doesn't work when I change the source from csv to sql (I get a lot of errors). I am able to fill y with the table values but the rest of my script doesn't seem setup to use it correctly. So my question is: After importing from SQL using sqlQuery, can I format it the same way as the .csv so that I can avoid errors such as "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" and "Error in rep(1, nrow(xxxx)) : invalid 'times' argument"?

Thanks for any help or direction you can point me in.

---

```
> dput(head(from_sql))
structure(list(school_year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = "2010-2011", class = "factor"), student_number = c(689322L, 
698048L, 698048L, 720067L, 720067L, 725021L), teacher_dpsid = c(100192400L, 
100192400L, 100192400L, 100192400L, 100192400L, 100192400L), 
    school_number = c(459L, 459L, 459L, 459L, 459L, 459L), test_category = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "C", class = "factor"), 
    test_name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "CNAME", class = "factor"), 
    measure_name = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("M", 
    "R", "W"), class = "factor"), course_code = c(1356L, 
    1356L, 1356L, 1356L, 1356L, 1356L), course_name = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), grade_name = c(10L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), test_date = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), batteryx = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = ".", class = "factor"), 
    rs = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = ".", class = "factor"), 
    ss = c(452L, 638L, 529L, 599L, 484L, 594L), proficiency = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), semesterx = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = ".", class = "factor"), 
    NP = c(24L, 97L, 96L, 77L, 91L, 80L), schoolyear = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), assessment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "xxxx", class = "factor")), .Names = c("school_year", 
"student_number", "teacher_dpsid", "school_number", "test_category", 
"test_name", "measure_name", "course_code", "course_name", "grade_name", 
"test_date", "batteryx", "rs", "ss", "proficiency", "semesterx", 
"NP", "schoolyear", "assessment"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

```
> dput(head(from_csv))
structure(list(school_year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = "2010-2011", class = "factor"), student_number = c(3466L, 
3466L, 3466L, 3466L, 3466L, 3466L), teacher_dpsid = c(150L, 150L, 
201L, 201L, 201L, 201L), school_number = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), test_category = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "C", class = "factor"), 
    test_name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("CMh", 
    "CR", "CW"), class = "factor"), measure_name = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("M", "R", "W"
    ), class = "factor"), course_code = c(4330L, 4331L, 1400L, 
    1405L, 1400L, 1405L), course_name = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), grade_name = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), test_date = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), batteryx = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = ".", class = "factor"), rs = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = ".", class = "factor"), ss = c(541L, 
    705L, 742L, 706L, 439L, 535L), proficiency = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), semesterx = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = ".", class = "factor"), np = c(59L, 56L, 3L, 
    18L, 39L, 69L), schoolyear = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), assessment = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("CM2010-2011", "CM2011-2012", 
    "CR2010-2011", "CR2011-2012", "CW2010-2011", 
    "CW2011-2012"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("school_year", 
"student_number", "teacher_dpsid", "school_number", "test_category", 
"test_name", "measure_name", "course_code", "course_name", "grade_name", 
"test_date", "batteryx", "rs", "ss", "proficiency", "semesterx", 
"np", "schoolyear", "assessment"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Completely impossible to say without actually having the two different data sets in hand. Something is different about the data in the two cases, and at the moment, you're the only one who has access to that information.

Comment: You should be able to get identical data in R from whichever source. If you're having problems, your imports aren't working as you think. Try running `from_csv <- read.csv("data.csv")` and `from_sql <- sqlQuery(ch, "select * from table")` and looking at `str(head(from_csv))` and `str(head(from_sql))` to see how they are different.

Comment: And, if you still don't know, edit your question to include the results of `dput(head(from_sql))` and `dput(head(from_csv))`.

Comment: Thanks guys. Shujaa, that is very helpful. I'm new to R so little things like that are still new to me. I'm noticing little differences such as in in my sql data.frame a filed is an int and in the csv it is a "factor w/ 2 levels..." Not quite sure how to resolve but I will research and change the datatypes in my sql to try to get it to match. Thanks again.

Comment: @shujaa I am still having issues so I edited my post to include the dputs above as you suggested. The data is a bit different which is expected and OK but I think the issue lies with the column types. Any ideas how to resolve?

Comment: Why does your sql data example have zero rows?

Comment: @joran, good catch. I fixed that now. Please see the revised edit for dput(head(from_sql))

Comment: The CSV read is likely giving factors because there are some NULL entries, whereas the SQL read casts the NULLs as NAs so it can still be an int. Pretty sure that's what the issue is.

Comment: @TommyLevi thanks for the reply. that does make some sense. what would be the easiest way to resolve? is there a simple something I can do to make them identical?

Comment: Look up both SQLQuery and read.csv for NULL/NA handling and play around till they agree. Alternatively post-process with a subset on `=='NULL'` or a `is.na()`